# Why when rotating an object with the mouse it's rotating to the opposite direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1.0f;


    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

I want to rotate an object smooth with the mouse.

But in this case if I move the mouse to the right it's rotating the object to the left and if moving up the mouse it's rotating down.

Comment: Have you tried just doing  `* -1` on both the X and Y inputs?

Comment: @Joelius This is working. But why it's changing also the Z axis if the Z is set to 0 ? And why it's hard while the game is playing to correct the Z back to 0 using the mouse ?

Comment: You hardcoded the Z to 0 I don't think that should change when you move the mouse but I'm not very familiar with Unity so I might just be missing something obvious.

Comment: The Z value is changing because setting the angle as a Euler angle causes a conversion to a Quaternion (which is how rotation is handled natively). As such this Quaternion is converted *back* to a Euler angle and displayed in the inspector. Because Euler and Quaternion representations are not 1:1, the resulting Euler is both (a) not guaranteed to be the same nor (b) guaranteed to be 0 on the Z.

Answer (score 0):

This is working just like I wanted :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseOrbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedH = 2.0f;
    public float speedV = 2.0f;

    private float yaw = 180.0f;
    private float pitch = 0.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        yaw -= speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }
}
```